# WSO2 ESB Aggregate from different responses

Tags: wso2, aggregation

I am bit confused with WSO2 ESB aggregator mediator.

I need to send three messages to different systems via WebServices, but the three systems have different message formats, so i need to transform each response to canonical model before validate onComplete expression, how can i achieve this?

Thanks for your quick response!

I know that XSLT transformation is what i need to transform the response message, but the problem is i don't know where to put it. What i understand is the onComplete section needs a xpath expression from response message, but the three message have different xpath values.

for example:

Response 1:

`<ns:getCustomerInfoResponse>
    <ns:Status>
        <ns1:Code>0</ns1:Code>
        <ns1:Desc>SUCCESS</ns1:Desc>
    </ns:Status>
</ns:getCustomerInfoResponse>`

Response 2:

`<v1:findByIdResponse>
        <output>
            <StatusCode>0</StatusCode>
            <StatusDesc>OK</StatusDesc>
        </output>
    </v1:findByIdResponse>`

What i need is transform two (or three) responses to unique canonical response before validate onComplete expression to something like:

`<ns:response>
        <status>
            <code>0</code>
            <desc>SUCCESS</desc>
        </status>
    </ns:response>`

Thanks.

---

Thanks Ratha for your response.

Consider the following scenario:

In a bank there are three different systems: Credit System, CoreBanking System and CRM system.

I need to do something like "get all balances from all products", so, the request is the customer id, then the customer id is sent to CRM for obtaining all customer products. Depending of the product (Credit Card or Savings Account) it needs to send the customer id to Credit System or CoreBanking. Finally, each system will response and the ESB needs to response with both balances.

Hope you can help me with this use case!

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is right to use aggregate mediator here, since you are receiving different responses from the service endpoints, which can not be correlated using xpath.
Aggregate mediator, which can be used along with clone/iterate mediators. Clone and iterate mediator is used to send same requests to multiple endpoint/such like scenarios.

My questions;
Are you sending same request to different endpoints and which are responding different type of responses? If so, it looks  bit wrong, how you defined your services.

If you are sending different requests and getting different response, and want to aggregate( or create a new reponse) based on the responses which you received from your backend services, it will fall into service chaining pattern, which you can find in the ESB documentation.
Hope this is clear to you.

Comment: Thanks Ratha for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSLT mediator to get messages in to a unified format. please refer [1] for the XSLT mediator sample.

[1]. http://wso2.org/project/esb/java/3.0.1/docs/mediators/xslt.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: Thanks Dharshana, please take a look to the question extension for understanding better my need. Regards.

Comment: Your link is dead, new is here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/XSLT+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](http://blog.afkham.org/2012/05/scatter-gather-eip-with-wso2-esb.html) also explains your scenario with a sample...

Comment: Thanks Reka, please take a look to the question extension for understanding better my need. Regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a combination of service chaining, transformation and iteration/aggregation.

So you start by sending the request to the CRM System, it will then respond with the different products, subdivided into Credit Card or Saving Account.

Then you could use two iterate mediators to split the response into the different requests for the two endpoints and collect the responses by using the aggregate or property mediator in the response sequences.

Now that you have the responses of the Credit System and CoreBanking service, you can start to transform (XSLT) and aggregate them to your response (balances).

[Here](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining) you can find an example for service chaining and a bit of XSLT transformation.

Regards.